# Is this a valid/safe way to clone any object/function/etc. in ES6?

Tags: javascript, variables, ecmascript-6, clone, immutability

I'm wondering whether this is a safe approach to cloning a variable that could be anything:

```
// the original variable definition:
let varIWantToCopy = 'hello world'

// the clone variable's definition:
let {varIWantToCopy: cloneOfVarIWantToCopy} = {varIWantToCopy}

// mutating the original value:
varIWantToCopy = 'goodbye world'

// should log out 'hello world':
console.log(cloneOfVarIWantToCopy)
```

Thank you for taking the time to look this over.

Kind regards,

Harry

Comment: No, because no clone or copy is made by that code. There is no native facility for a general-case "clone" or "copy" from an object because what that means is subjective.

Comment: strings are immutable.  You can just do `let clone = varIWantToCopy` and then you can modify clone without affecting `varIWantToCopy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use lodash if you really want to clone an object.
[There are several clone functions in lodash that you can use depending on your requirements.](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#cloneDeep)

```
// or you can use lodash/clone
import cloneDeep from 'lodash/cloneDeep';

var objects = [{ 'a': 1 }, { 'b': 2 }];

var cloned = cloneDeep(objects);

console.log(cloned[0] === objects[0]); // this will be false
```

So if you change the value of cloned[0], the value of object[0] won't change.

Comment: Thank you @xeiton! Would this work if a function was assigned to `objects`?

Comment: @HarrySolovay, I am not 100% sure, but my guess is that it should work with functions too, since functions are a type of object in JS. 
If this answer helped you please accept as an answer or up-vote, or both :P  ... Thank you!